# FTP'ing a Suave app to Azure

Tags: azure, f#, suave

Having never used `Azure` before I'm attempting to deploy a simple `F#` `Suave` app to `Azure` using `FTP`. Ultimately I want to deploy via `github` but I initially thought `FTP`'ing it would be the easy first step. According to https://suave.io/azure-app-service.html it should be straight forward.

These are the steps I followed

1. Created a new web app in Azure including a resource group
   and app service plan. All on the Free Tier.
2. Downloaded the `publishsettings` `XML` file that Azure created.
3. Cloned this repo: https://github.com/isaacabraham/fsharp-demonstrator
4. Used FileZilla to connect via FTP using the creds
   from step 2.
5. Uploaded the files (via FTP) from
   fsharp-demonstrator/src/SuaveHost (which includes the necessary `web.config` file) from the repo cloned at step 3 to
   the site\wwwroot on Azure.
6. Navigated to `Azure` site url.

Then I receive the error:

**The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.**

(When I look at the folders on Azure under site\wwwroot I don't see any obj or bin folders. I don't think any msbuild process occurred. That doesn't seem right.)

Anybody got any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that when you deploy via FTP, then Azure does not automatically run the deploy script specified in [the `.deployment` file](https://github.com/isaacabraham/fsharp-demonstrator/blob/master/.deployment).

- The `build.fsx` script uses Kudu service to deploy the built files, so it might be easier to just use Github deployment rather than FTP - this way, Azure will do the deployment for you.
- If you want to deploy via FTP, you'll need to build the project locally and upload the output. I'm not sure how to best do this with Isaac's Kudu-based demo though (ultimately, you need `web.config` that points to your built executable [like this](https://github.com/the-gamma/thegamma-services/blob/master/web.config#L13))

Comment: Thanks for replying Tomas, I'm not really getting anywhere with this. I tried building locally and uploading the `.exe` but that didn't work either.  I've posted issues on the `Suave` github repo and on Isaac's repo (https://github.com/isaacabraham/fsharp-demonstrator)  in the hope of more detailed instructions on how to actually `FTP` `Suave` apps to `Azure`. Thanks anyway.